# How to get Researcher Hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2015, winter-bash

How i am supposed to get a Researcher Hat for Winter BASH 2015? I tried to use the site search functionality on 3 consecutive UTC days.

Comment: any reason for the down vote?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the on-site search (not Google) on the same site on three consecutive UTC days.  That's how I got it.

(The hat description seems pretty clear to me.  Did you perhaps search on different sites or skip a day?)

Comment: OP's probably used the SE search, which is google search.

Comment: @nicael ?  I'm saying you need to type your query into the search box on the SE site.  A lot of people use Google -- that is, go to Google and then restrict the search to SE -- which won't work for this hat.  (How could it?  The hat isn't tied to referrer links; it's tied to user actions on-site.)

Comment: Nonono, I mean that OP has probably used the search on stackexchange.com and surprised why didn't he get the hat. Thats just an assumption.

Comment: As for your answer, it's clear of course.